# SSH painfully slow on my local network?

Tags: centos, ssh, virtual-machines

I have a CentOS 6-x64 Server running through VirtualBox on Windows Server 2012R2, but whenever I SSH into it, it's painfully slow.  This happens for both Putty on Windows, and SSH on OS X.  I've read through countless of posts about slow login, but this is just an all-around sluggishness.

These are the things I have checked:

- I've disabled DNS for sshd
- I'm connecting using an IP address on the same subnet
- There isn't massive traffic going to or from the host machine

Comment: What are the MAC addresses of your guest and host(s)? Where are you sshing from and to (from the windows host to the centos guest?)?

Comment: I'm sshing from a different windows box to the CentOS.

Comment: Do you have MAC address conflicts?

Comment: There are no MAC address conflicts, and I've cleared the ARP cache on all of my devices.  I'm still having awful performance.

Comment: Have you checked the MTU's of the network devices ?  Maybe smaller MTUs will solve the problem - particularly if the problem occurs when you are browsing a large amount of text (like a directory listing)

Answer (score 3):

At first you must do some experiments and exams:

1. Did you try other protocols? Leave some big file inside apache/httpd server and try to get. Idea is to recognize, problem is with SSH or network
2. See to network intarface statistics. Are there any errors?
3. Try ping. I hope you didn't enable packet filtering. Try ping with big packets: ping -s 1500 some.ip.address and look what you'll get. Wery often problem is hidden when you examine network using standard small ping packets
4. Try bigger ping, about -s 2000 or 3000 . Don't worry. Max ethernet packet size is 1500, but this ping will be splitted. You will test fragmented packets can be properly shipped over network.
5. Try connect devices directly using crossed patchcord. Maybe you eth switch is damaged? Maybe it keeps some unneeded MAC's, or is configured for MAC filtering?

This should be asked at first, but I'm asking this at the last: What does you mean "is slow in SSH"? Connecting or transfer? When connecting, this is may be a DNS problem. When transfer, usually this is network problem. You have linux machine, then you can do tcpdump on the linux machine. then you can recognize, this is DNS problem on the ssh server or on the client. on client side you can simply use servers IP address for workaround problem on client, then you are sure it is problem on server side that is trying reverse resolve your IP addres before it will be written to ssh log file. If it is still the problem, you can reconfigure ssh for disable reverse dns resolving. But main idea is repair DNS configuration and preventing reverse resolving for local IP area.

At the past I have got similar problem. My 3com switch was damaged. In some situations this made duplicated packets. Firmware upgrades didn't resolve problem, then I had to buy another one. Maybe you can borrow for a moment some switch and temporarly replace your, then check all is ok. Poor checking is removing switch and connect devices directly. Of course DHCP server will be unavailable, and temporarly you should define networks statically.

Good luck, I hope this will help you.

Comment: Upvoted your answer so that you will have the ability to insert comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Because this is pretty high in Google search results, here's my stab. I fixed sluggish ssh and high ping latencies on my local WiFi network by turning off WiFi Power Saver (on Linux) but might be applicable to other OS's too.

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`

Replace wlan0 with the name of your wireless interface if it's different. You'll have to make this change permanent by adapting systemd or other configs (see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently)

Comment: You're a life-saver, you really are!